# How to make last two digit price is always 00? Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, price, currency

I set $1 = 1150 KRW as currency rate. Is there any way I can show the last two digits of KRW is always 00?

For example, if the product price is $15.5(15.5 x 1150=17,820 KRW), but I want to show 17,800 KRW (last two digits 00)

Answer (score 1):

Use this in the end

`floor( $finalNumber / 100 ) * 100`

Works for me perfectly.

Thank you